# How to access to all possible view controllers in a tabBarViewController from storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to programmatically construct a replica of the storyboard tabBarController, as follows:

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarViewController")
   viewControllers = tabBarController.childViewControllers
```

My storyboard tabBarController contains 7 tabs. But the code above only provide me with the 4 firsts (on iPhone). How can I get the others tabs from the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are using wrong property to get `viewcontrollers`. You should use [viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621185-viewcontrollers) instead of [childViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621452-childviewcontrollers). Try the code below, it will return 7 controllers for `viewControllers` value

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarViewController") as! UITabBarController
let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
```